# Length conversion program cannot convert decimal number in C++

Tags: c++

I have to write a program that takes length as input in feet and inches and the program should then convert the lengths in centimeters and display it on screen. So this is my code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{


    double totalinches;
    double centimeter;
    float inch_to_centimeter = 2.54f;
    int feet_to_inch = 12;
    int feet;
    int inch;


    cout << "Enter the length in feet:";
    cin >> feet;
    cout << "Enter the length in inches:\n ";
    cin >> inch;

    totalinches = (feet * feet_to_inch) + inch;
    cout << "Total length in inches:\n ";
    cout << totalinches;

    centimeter = totalinches * (inch_to_centimeter);
    cout << "The number of centimeter= ";
    cout << centimeter;
```

When I run the code, the code can only calculate natural number (non-decimal number) but whenever I type decimal number, the code is error. This is the error that I got when I type decimal number. The code itself skip the "Enter the length in inches" and the result is always 60 and 152.4. Sorry for my bad English and i am new to code.

```
Enter the length in feet:5.74
Enter the length in inches:
Total length in inches:
60The number of centimeter= 152.4
C:\Dev\C++\HomeWork\Debug\HomeWork.exe (process 22468) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

Comment: The variable `feet` is of type `int`. How exactly do you expect it to store the value `5.74`?

Comment: Integer types like `int` can't store fractions.